# NullReferenceException thrown?

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

I get this exception:

```
NullReferenceException
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
   at Namespace.TheClass.TheMethod()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

in this code:

```
public class TheClass : TheBaseClass
{
    protected IList1 List;
    public object Object1;
    public ManualResetEvent MrEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    readonly Attr1 Attr1;
    readonly Attr2 Attr2;
    readonly EventHandler<Class1> BeginHandler, EndHandler;
    readonly EventHandler<Class2> Handler2;
    readonly EventHandler<Class3> Handler3;

    public TheClass(Attr1 attr1, Attr2 attr2, EventHandler<Class1> beginHandler, EventHandler<Class1> endHandler, EventHandler<Class2> handler2, EventHandler<Class3> handler3)
    {
        this.Attr1 = attr1;
        this.Attr2 = attr2;
        this.BeginHandler = beginHandler;
        this.EndHandler = endHandler;
        this.Handler2 = handler2;
        this.Handler3 = handler3;
        Thread t = new Thread(Run);
        t.IsBackground = true;
        t.Start();
    }

    void TheMethod()
    {
        Args1 args1 = new Args1();
        if (BeginHandler != null)
        {
            try
            {
                BeginHandler(this, args1);
            }
            catch { }
        }

        try
        {
            List = GetList(args1);
        }
        catch { }

        if (List != null)
        {
            List.Event1 += new EventHandler<Args2>(List_Event1);
        }

        if (Handler3 != null)
        {
            try
            {
                Args3 args3 = new Args3(args1.Attr1, args1.Attr2);
                Handler3(this, args3);
                this.Object1 = args3.Object1;
            }
            catch { }
        }

        if (this.Object1 == null)
        {
            if (args1.Attr1 != null)
                try
                {
                    this.Object1 = Class4.GetObject(args1.Attr1);
                }
                catch { }
        }

        MrEvent.Set();
        Method1();
        Method2();

        if (List != null)
        {
            List.Event1 -= new EventHandler<Args2>(List_Event1);
        }

        if (EndHandler != null)
        {
            try
            {
                EndHandler(this, args1);
            }
            catch { }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't see any place where the mentioned handle null exception could be thrown. Do you see anyone?

*To Veer: How could you changed meaning of my question so much?

To those who approved it: How could you agree with it?*

Comment: Empty catch clauses are evil.

Comment: `catch { }` Shutting up exception is bad, very bad.

Comment: I don't hink it's possible to find the exception from this code. Why don't you debug it line by line and find the exception place?

Comment: Just debug your project and the line that throws the exception will be highlighted.

Comment: Are you really telling us, that you can write multithreaded code, but for some reason you cannot find your F5 key? It's in the middle of your keyboard in the upper row, right next to F6 and a little to the right of F4. It starts the debugger.

Comment: OK, to make it clear. **This is not my code and I can't rework it**, because it is from a library, which I use. Debugging is also problem, because the exception occures only sometimes and unpredictably and I personally have never saw it, so I have to work only theoretically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NullReferenceException can be thrown from inlined methods. Look into Method1 and Method2.

Answer (score 1):

In this code, inside the try catch block you will not get the null exception because catch block is empty so, Exception will not thrown out side, check other objects.

Comment: Which other objects should I check? Exception is from this method according to stack trace.

Comment: Are you sending a parameter from outside to this constructor(TheClass)

Comment: Make sure that the all parameter not null

Comment: Check Method1(); Method2();

Comment: Thank you Vikram, I'll check them, but when the exception would be thrown from one of them, it would be on the stack trace and it is not there.

Comment: I am passing parameters from outside, but they are not used in TheMethod, or they are used with null checking, so it shouldn't cause the exception. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes correct, There is no chance to null here, you are telling sometimes getting null, so sending the parameter is the problem it seems, Best way you can try to put test application and check it.